# How can we manage cordova project with svn?

Tags: cordova, svn, plugins

everyone. 
    We are working a cordova project and have some trouble in managing our code with svn. One of our guy added a customized plugin with CLI, and this would change the config.xml file under platforms directory and add some new files as well.So this guy committed those modified files to svn server. While the other guys checked out a new version of the code from the svn server and built with CLI on their own computer, something's very wrong. Because the command 'cordova build ios' will remove 'www' under platforms dir and copy from the external 'www',this will definitely undo the plugin. 
So what should we do about it? Any help,please.Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend not checking in the platform and plugin folders to source control. If you add `--save` to the platform and plugin add command, it will create an entry in the main config.xml. Then when running prepare, Cordova will install all missing plugins and platforms.

For the custom plugin, the easiest solution is probably to save it locally outside the Cordova project. So your directory might look like this:

```
CordovaApp/
CustomPlugin/
```

Then within your Cordova project, run `cordova plugin add ../CustomPlugin --save` and it will install the plugin and save the source location. Then as long as both folders are checked in, when someone builds CordovaApp it will pull the custom plugin from that folder.

You could also look into a private npm or git repository for hosting the custom plugin. I haven't tried either of those though.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. But what about the customized plugin? Where should we keep it? Should we keep it on svn? Because it only exists on someone's Mac. We should keep the customized plugin somewhere others can access,right?

Comment: sorry I missed that part. I've added some info

Comment: Thank u conner. It's really a big help. I'll check this out. And I'll mark your reply as an answer.Thanks again!